# Extract numeric values from string in mysql without creating any function

Tags: mysql

I have one string like "H2O" and i want to extract the numeric value from given string in mysql without creating any custom function.

For Ex. String          = "H2O"
        Expected output =  2

I tried regex expression to check whether string contains numeric value or not its working but i want to extract that numeric value.

Please anyone can help me out.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What if the string is `ABC123` or `A2B3C4`?

Comment: Its very simple by using REGEXP. Please share your try with us so that we can help you.

Comment: @Bikash P : I tried regex to check whether string contains numeric value or not

Comment: @GordonLinoff : It doesnt matter

Comment: Can you post your try?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: Tried this REGEXP '.*[^0-9]*[^0-9]*.*'  to check whether string contains numeric value or not but it is not returning any value

Comment: @BikashP REGEXP '.*[^0-9]*[^0-9]*.*'

Comment: @AnkitBajpai : Can you tell me the simple solution according to my expected result?

Comment: Can you please try this - ' ^[0-9]+$ '